# How to use Stub object with tinytest and meteorjs?

Tags: testing, meteor, meteor-velocity

This weekend i tryed to test a package "A" from my meteor app.
This package depends on another package "B" that defines all collections. So the package "B" expose all required collections.

The package "A" expose a main object that have some methods that use the collections exposed in "B".

I want to replace some collections by a code like this :

```
myCol = {
    "findOne": return {_id: 1, "name": ben}
}
```

But it fails. This code is ok from tinytest.add code, but in the methods of the package "A", it still uses the original Collection variables. I've seen in the build folder that everything is re-written by the build system, so i wonder what is the best way to test my code without depending on those Collection variables.
I have some ideas like storing those variables in a main object that has get/set methods. It might allow me to change everything when i do test.

Thanks for help

Here is the sample app : https://github.com/MeteorLyon/tutorial-package-dependancy-testing
Follow the README.md to run different test.
If you find a solution it's great.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for stubs, I'd highly recommend using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/). Specifically, have a look at the [stubs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) and the [sandbox](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sandbox) portions of the docs. You can find atmosphere packages [here](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=sinon). Here's a quick example:

```js
Tinytest.add('my test', sinon.test(function(test) {
  // this is sandboxed stub - we are writing to a global object
  // but it will be restored at the end of the test
  test.stub(Meteor, 'userId', function() {
    return USER_ID;
  });

  // let's do the same thing with a collection
  test.stub(Posts, 'findOne', function() {
    return {_id: 1, name: 'ben'};
  });

  var post = Posts.findOne();
  test.equal(post.name, 'ben');
}));
```

Keep in mind that tinytest is an integration test framework, so you may get better tests by fully utilizing both package's APIs. With respect to testing collection interactions, we've found its better to not stub very much and just insert and cleanup as needed. But that's pretty general advice - there may be some specific reason why this can't work in your particular use case.

Comment: What if Posts is exported from one package B to package A ? Actually it seems that Posts is copyed intto package A like this :

var Posts = Package['packageA']['Posts'];

So if i write a Stubs for Posts, it will be available only in my test, but not in the tested package B that will still use original Posts.
I'm writting a sample app to illustrate this case.

Comment: Sounds good - just keep it as small as possible to illustrate the point. If you share the repo link I'll take a look.

Comment: Here is the sample app : https://github.com/MeteorLyon/tutorial-package-dependancy-testing
Follow the README.md to run different test.
If you find a solution it's great.

Comment: Thanks for those informations. One thing that really helped me is the testOnly parameters : api.export('ToBeTested', 'server', {testOnly: true}); that allow to export variables only in test environment. It allows you to stubs/mock everything. Even if insert/remove database is easy (if you have the scripts that allow to change mogo_url quicly) i prefer to use mock like in Java, PHP, ...